# How to auto-size a cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a small problem, about stretching the cell. I'm using the WSTagsField library.

```
class UITableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var tagsView: UIView!
}

class UITableViewController: UITableViewController {

     override func viewDidLoad() {
             tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
     }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

         return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
     }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tagField", for: indexPath) as! AddManuallyRecipeTableViewCell

            let tagsView = cell.tagsView!
            let tagsField = WSTagsField()

            tagsField.frame = tagsView.bounds
            tagsView.addSubview(tagsField)

            tagsField.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
            tagsField.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
            tagsField.placeholder = "Добавить тэг ..."
            tagsField.returnKeyType = .next
            tagsField.delimiter = " "

            tagsField.onDidChangeHeightTo = { tagField, height in
                print("HeightTo \(height)")
                tagsField.layoutSubviews()
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.endUpdates()

            }
}
```

there is a method that is called when a new string is created -> onDidChangeHeightTo. Here a new height is transferred.

[image]

Comment: You should also set `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. And  I think `tableView(_:estimatedHeightForRowAt:)` is the same as `tableView.estimatedRowHeight`, so overriding `tableView(_:estimatedHeightForRowAt:)` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in view did load and also check your constraints must be accurate... `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
 so your viewDidLoad will looks like.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
             tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
             tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
     }
```

Comment: im using this same code for resizing my cell on the basis of content.. 
using constrains must satisfy leading trailing top and bottom when content exceed my cell is expanding automatically ;O

Comment: It's all about the library WSTagsField. The rest of the cells work fine

Comment: autoresizing of cell is about tableview i think.. content is whatever you put in content view.